# Data is lost when sent to node.js socket

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets

I'm sending an image from my ios client. below are the codes:

```
- (void)sendmsg{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dsa.png"];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
   [outputstream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}
```

below are my server-side code:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer();
server.on('connection',function(socket){
        console.log('get connection.');
        socket.on('data',function(data){
                console.log(data.length);
            });
    });
server.listen(8125);
```

I checked the data size on both side, but I got the different outcome.

On the client-side the size I got is:

```
2015-01-19 23:50:01.083 NetWordDemo[1794:172737] 468644
```

On the server-side, sometime I got:

```
65536
65536
65536
65536
65536
65536
65536
9892
```

which is true. but other times I got:

```
65328
65536
65536
65536
65536
65536
65536
10100
```

and even:

```
48996
65536
65536
65536
65536
32300
```

This is really annoying!! I know it would be worse if I encode the row data into a string and insert the string into a json object.

Anyone knows why? I have come up with a delimiter method to handle the "split of data", but the data is not even enough to split. Why there would be some lost?!

Comment: `socket.on('data', ...)` will be called multiple times per large upload and each chunk can be any size.  You need to collect all the chunks from a given connection and look at the sum total of all the chunks.  You code appears to be assuming there is only one chunk arriving, but it may be many.

Comment: I know this method would be call multiple times. So I add all these numbers(each number is generated because of one chunk arriving) up to check if the size is correct.